# flask server can not work and show "Restarting with inotify reloader"

Tags: python, flask

When I start the server, the console shows

```
python2 web.py
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8005/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with inotify reloader
```

And if I tried to make a request to the server, the flask server will be down.

I have no ideas what's wrong on it, it didn't throws any error log.

Here are what I imported

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from flask import request, url_for
from flask import json
from flask import Response
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_request_params import bind_request_params
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pymongo
import pdb
from webargs import Arg
from webargs.flaskparser import use_args, use_kwargs
import urlparse
from mongo import Mongo
import yaml
import time, functools
from functools import wraps
from pdb import set_trace
from flask import g
from pandas_helper import PandasHelper
```

Answer (score 0):

inotify seems to be coming from Werkzeug, but I can't find anything suggesting that it should be using 0.0.0.0- this only appears with the inbuilt development server run function.

For development work werkzeug [suggests](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/):

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response

@Request.application
def application(request):
    return Response('Hello World!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 4000, application)
```